# mysql Trying to select from table if search term is already in table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute a MySQL case that will conduct different selection criteria dependent on inputs. To be more specific If the user selects an option on an html form, I want the case to search within a table to see if an entry exists to match that option.

```
"CASE 
            WHEN $destinationID NOT IN destinationexceptions.destinationid THEN
                SELECT file, destination, visa
                FROM output INNER JOIN file
                ON output.fileid=file.id
                INNER JOIN destination
                ON output.destinationid=destination.id
                INNER JOIN visatype
                ON output.visaid=visatype.id
                WHERE output.destinationid='$destinationID'
                AND output.visaid='$visaID'

            ELSE $destinationID IN destinationexceptions.destinationid THEN
                CASE
                    WHEN $nationalityID = destinationexceptions.nationalityid THEN
                        SELECT destinationid, nationalityid, file
                        FROM destinationexceptions
                        WHERE destinationid = '$destinationID'
                        AND nationalityid = '$nationalityID'
                        INNER JOIN file
                        ON destinationexceptions.fileid=file.id
                    ELSE
                        SELECT file, destination, visa
                        FROM output INNER JOIN file
                        ON output.fileid=file.id
                        INNER JOIN destination
                        ON output.destinationid=destination.id
                        INNER JOIN visatype
                        ON output.visaid=visatype.id
                        WHERE output.destinationid='$destinationID'
                        AND output.visaid='$visaID'
                END CASE
        END CASE";
```

So far as I can see my issue is that the query doesn't want to look in the table to see if there's a match. Inevitably the error is a 1064 access or syntax error.

Thanks all

Comment: This is the entire query? Because if so, it is very wrong.

Comment: @BartFriederichs This would probably explain it, obviously it kills the DRY coding principles but I wanted something that worked first and foremost. Where do you suggest I start?

Comment: This *seems* back-to-front